# How to stop my PC waking from AMD USB3.1 eXtensible Host Controller?

Tags: windows-7, usb, sleep, wake-up

Windows 7 x64
RAM 16GB Fury
Mother ASrock B450 Steel Legend
CPU Ryzen 5 1600
GPU RX 580

My PC wakes from AMD USB3.1 eXtensible Host Controller but there's no "Power Management" tab in the device administrator to enable or disable anything related to power.

**powercfg -devicequery wake_armed** list nothing.

**powercfg -lastwake**
Recuento de historial de activaci¾n - 1
Historial de activaci¾n [0]
  Recuento de origen de activaci¾n - 1
  Origen de activaci¾n [0]
    Tipo: dispositivo
    Ruta de acceso de instancia: PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_43D5&SUBSYS_43D01849&REV_01\4&288c77c7&0&000B
    Nombre descriptivo:
    Descripci¾n: AMD USB3.1 eXtensible Host Controller
    Fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.

**powercfg -waketimers**(No wake timers)
No hay temporizadores de activaci¾n activos en el sistema.

**powercfg -devicequery wake_programmable**
Mouse compatible con HID (001)
Dispositivo de teclado HID
Dispositivo de control del consumidor compatible con HID
Dispositivo compatible con HID
Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller

How this is possible? There's no power management for that device but it can wake my PC.
I want to able suspend the PC from Windows and wake up only from motherboard/case power button.
I have my mouse connected to a cheap USB HUB Can be that?

**ACPI**
[image: ACPI PS/2]

**USB Wake Support**
[image: Win7 USB Wake Support]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried managing the ACPI settings in the bios?
If not, Boot into the bios and do the following:

1. Go to the advanced tab
2. Click ACPI Configuration
3. Find an option that applies to your USB device and disable computer wakeup support

Comment: I just added photos about that, all seems to be disabled.